# Prove some facts about fixed points on the sphere using differential topology

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I'm reading Differential Topology by Guillemin & Pollack, and I would like to know how to prove these facts about fixed points on the sphere in this viewpoint:)

Let $f,g \in {C^0}({\mathbb{S}^{k}},{\mathbb{S}^{k}})$.

(1) If $\deg f \ne {( - 1)^{k + 1}}$, then there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=x_0$.

(2) If $\deg f \ne 1$, then there exists $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=-x_0$.

(3) if $k$ is even, then one of the three maps $f,g,g \circ f$ has a fixed point.

I've been working on them for a while but still can't see the path. Maybe my understanding is not deep enough... Could anyone give me some instructions? Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: You say $f, g$ are elements of $C^0(S^k, S^k)$ - what you have learnt in G&P is not sufficient to prove this fact. You can at best prove all of this for smooth functions, and then use smooth approximation to prove it for continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments there are good approximation theorems to pass from the smooth to the continuous case, which is why I'll be considering smooth functions from here on out.

A useful result when dealing with antipodes is the following :

> **Lemma 1 :** *Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and $f,g : X \to S^n$ smooth functions such that that for all $x \in X$,
>   $$
> ||f(x)-g(x)||<2
> $$
>   Then $f$ and $g$ are smoothly homotopic.*

It is a good exercise to prove this (consider the straight line homotopy from $f$ to $g$. What can you say about it ?). The second observation you might need is that the antipodal map $a :S^n \to S^n$ 
$$
(x_1,...,x_{n+1}) \mapsto (-x_1,...,-x_{n+1})
$$
has degree $(-1)^{n+1}$. To show this rewrite it as a composition of reflexions on the $i^{th}$ coordinate, and use the fact that the degree of a composition is the product of the degrees.

Equipped with these results we can show what you want :

**(1)**  Consider the contraposition, and suppose that $f$ has no fixed point. Then, for all $x \in S^n$,
$$
||f(x)-(-x)||<2
$$
(You can show this). What does lemma 1 tell you ? Can you conclude ?

**(2)** You can use the exact same line of reasoning (remember that the identity map has degree 1).

**(3)** Suppose that none of these mappings have a fixed point. Then by (1), $f,g$ and $g \circ f$ all have degree $(-1)^{k+1}=-1$ (since $k$ is even). However, 
$$
deg(g\circ f)=deg(g)deg(f)=(-1)^2=1
$$
Which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

(1) and (2) are equivalent since the antipodal map has degree $-(-1)^k$.

To prove (2), if $f(x)\ne-x$ then there is a homotopy from $f$
to the identity map, defined by following the shortest
path on the sphere from $f(x)$ to $x$.

For (3), note that if not, all of $f$, $g$ and $g\circ f$ would have degree $-1$.

Comment: You have the sign wrong on the degree if the antipodal map. It's not totally clear from your verbal description in (2) that this gives a smooth homotopy.